# How do i create a time delay before the button appears unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, timedelay

I am creating an interactive video using Unity/C#. I am doing this using scenes and buttons that when clicked, go to the next scene or back. However, I want the buttons to appear once the video is finished. Is there any way I can add a delay to the buttons before they appear in the scene when playing?

Comment: simply you use Coroutine and delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time delay you could use coroutines. Check it out [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) There is options like waitforseconds so you can delay your button apperance. here is sample code

```
private IEnumerator ShowBtn()
{
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => videoplayer.isPlaying);
    // show visibility of your button
}
```

And when you play video call this function like this

```
StartCoroutine(ShowBtn());
```

Comment: thank you very much is solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. [isPlaying](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-isPlaying.html).

A simple script would look like this.

```cs
if(videoplayer.isPlaying == false && videoWasPlayed == true){
  btn.active = true;
  videoWasPlayed = false;
}
```

`videoWasPlayed` is used to check if the video was ever played. This would need to be set to true when the video is played.